# Image in a calendar event

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, calendar, events

Is there a way you can add an image on an event and have that image display on the event on the Month View of a Calendar?  Possibly a link or an attachment?  For instance, if the image shows a small icon of CEO, CFO, CIO, etc., it will be part of the text displayed on the event along with the verbiage?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no out-of-the-box method to achieve this requirement.

But the month view contains the event ID .
[image]

You could add a image column in current list and you could use code to read all id in current page after page loaded, then you can read the corresponding image url according to the ID and insert the image to the view.

Or you could create a spfx to rebuild a custom view about the calendar,you could design this view according to your needs.

Sample：

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-calendar